# Global Value Set

Tags: apex, metadata, custom-metadata

I have created a GlobalValueSet using salesforce metadata api. Now I am creating a new field on a existing object using SF metadata api which is going to use this GlobalValueSet, but somehow its failing to deploy giving me following error : Error: You must specify either picklist, globalPicklist, or valueSet.

Following is object field metadata and I tried using all the types ex: valueSet, globalPicklist, globalValueSet possible to get through this, but none works. Anyone has a idea how do we reference GlobalValueSets when creating a new picklist field ?

```
<fields>
    <fullName>global_time__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>global time</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <valueSet>Start_End_Time__c</valueSet>
    <type>Picklist</type>
</fields>
```

Comment: What version of the API are you using?

Comment: using version 38.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<valueSet>` isn't just a value. It requires more. It should be:

```
<valueSet>
  <restricted>true</restricted>
  <valueSetName>Start_End_Time__c</valueSetName>
</valueSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<fields>
    <fullName>YourPicklistField__c</fullName>
    <description>Field description</description>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <globalPicklist>GlobalPicklistName</globalPicklist>
    <inlineHelpText>Helptext text.</inlineHelpText>
    <label>The field Label goes here</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Picklist</type>
</fields>
```

This is how the field metadata is retrieved from the organization. You should use `globalPicklist`.

Information on how to describe the value set can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalvalueset.htm).

Comment: `globalPicklist` is only available in version 37.0 of the API. It has been replaced by `valueSet`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I extracted this snippet using the Force-CLI, which apparently was discontinued. :( Sad!